# Google Map Direction request denied

Tags: javascript

DIRECTIONS_ROUTE: REQUEST_DENIED: There was an issue performing a Directions request.", stack: "Error: DIRECTIONS_ROUTE: REQUEST_DENIED: There was…Bxn-37h3KP_vNzLT1V7Zmb13riuqOLA&token=122369:1:28", name: "MapsRequestError", endpoint: "DIRECTIONS_ROUTE", code: "REQUEST_DENIED"}
name: "MapsRequestError"
endpoint: "DIRECTIONS_ROUTE"
code: "REQUEST_DENIED"

Comment: Directions request failed due to REQUEST_DENIED

Answer (score 1):

From 16th July, 2018 onwards:

```
Direction API, Street View, Geolocation are in premier basis.
```

You need to subscribe it by paying on monthly basis.

Answer (score 0):

For display route in map we need to enable **Directions API.**

1.Go to the Google Cloud Platform Console.

2.Click the Select a project button, then select the same project you set up for the Maps JavaScript API and click Open.

3.From the list of APIs on the Dashboard, look for Directions API.

4.If you see the API in the list, you’re all set. If the API is not listed, enable it:

- At the top of the page, select ENABLE API to display the Library tab. Alternatively, from the left side menu, select Library.
- Search for Directions API, then select it from the results list.
- Select ENABLE. When the process finishes, Directions API appears in the list of APIs on the Dashboard.